# How does Lambert's W behave near ∞?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, special-functions

How does $W$ behave near $+\infty$ compared to $\log$?  In particular, I'm interested in the asymptotic expansion of

$$\frac{W(x)}{\ln(x)}$$

near $\infty$ (but along the positive real line, if that matters).  Clearly $W(x)\sim\ln(x)$ as $x$ increases, and the next term looks hyperbolic.

Comment: charles, it goes to zero as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ its slower than log.

Comment: @Approximist: I don't think so.  W(10^10)/ln(10^10) = 0.86..., W(10^100)/ln(10^100) = 0.97..., and so forth.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lambert+w+function%2F+ln+x Go to the end of the page

Comment: @Approximist: Don't believe everything you read on W|A!  In this case the software misunderstood your meaning.  Try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+ProductLog[x]%2FLog[x]+as+x+goes+to+Infinity instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I think $1$ is a highly _probable_ limit for large x. lambertw(10^100); log(10^100)
224.843; 230.258 (this is clear if we just take first two terms in the expansion of W(z)=ln z - ln ln z)

Comment: This appears to work only for integers at infinity: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531276/lambertwk-k-by-tetration-for-natural-numbers

Comment: @MatsGranvik: How so?

Comment: I don't know. It is the exponentiated recurrence for numerators of Dirichlet series for logarithms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Theorem 2.7 of [this paper](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/JIPAM/images/107_07_JIPAM/107_07.pdf), for every $x \geq e$,
$$
\log x - \log \log x + \frac{1}{2}\frac{{\log \log x}}{{\log x}} \le W(x) \le \log x - \log \log x + \frac{e}{{e - 1}}\frac{{\log \log x}}{{\log x}}
$$
(with equality only for $x=e$). Note that $\frac{e}{{e - 1}} \approx 1.582$.

EDIT (cf. Juan's answer). According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), an asymptotic formula which yields reasonably accurate results for sufficiently large $x$ is 
$$
W(x) = L_1  - L_2  + \frac{{L_2 }}{{L_1 }} + \frac{{L_2 ( - 2 + L_2 )}}{{2L_1^2 }} + \frac{{L_2 (6 - 9L_2  + 2L_2^2 )}}{{6L_1^3 }}
$$
$$
+ \frac{{L_2 ( - 12 + 36L_2  - 22L_2^2  + 3L_2^3 )}}{{12L_1^4 }} + \frac{{L_2 (60 - 300L_2  + 350L_2^2  - 125L_2^3  + 12L_2^4 )}}{{60L_1^5 }} + O\bigg[\bigg(\frac{{L_2 }}{{L_1 }}\bigg)^6 \bigg],
$$
where
$$
L_1 = \log x
$$
$$
L_2 = \log \log x.
$$
Useful references can be found in that link.

Comment: The Mathematica result seems to contradict the Corless-Jeffrey-Knuth result that Juan Joder quotes below.  (The error term O(1/x) would instead be O((log log x/log x)^3) by that formula.)  Thoughts?

Comment: I deleted the paragraph referring to that result.

Comment: Good, the world makes sense again. :)  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

[One of the original papers by Corless *et al*.](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/CorlessJeffreyKnuth.pdf) on the Lambert function gives the following series expansion at $\infty$ for the (principal branch of the) Lambert function:

$$W_0(z)=\ln\;z-\ln\ln\;z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{\ln\;z}\right)^n \sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^m \left[n\atop{n-m+1}\right]\frac{(\ln\ln\;z)^m}{m!}$$

where $\left[n\atop m\right]$ is a Stirling cycle number.

Comment: +1 for referring to the Stirling number used as the 'Stirling cycle' number. Whoever originally named them '.. of the first kind' and '...of the 2nd kind' cost the world precious brain energy in trying to remember which was which.

Answer (score 0):

This Mathematica program takes a while to evaluate:

```
Clear[x, a, nn, b, z]
nn = 200;
z = 100
a = Series[Exp[-x], {x, N[Log[z], 500], nn}];
b = Normal[InverseSeries[Series[x/a, {x, 0, nn}]]];
x = z;
N[b, 20]
N[LambertW[x], 30]
```

It appears to give LambertW(100) = 3.3856301402900501849... but it uses 200 terms of the power series of Exp[-x] expanded at Log[100] to get there.