# How to solve $n$ for $n^n = 2^c$?

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions

> How to solve $n$ for $n^n = 2^c$?

What's the numerical method?

I don't get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5En+=+2%5E1000).

For $c=1000$, $n$ should be approximately $140$, right?

Comment: try something like solve(n^n = 2^1000,n) instead of what you did.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Where does this equation come up? Or is it just an exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpha sometimes goes off into the complex plane when what you want is only the reals.  I agree with you and get about 140.222.  If you ask to solve n(ln(n))=1000 ln(2) you get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Consider [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Hint 2: First take $\log$ on both sides.

And explicitly: The solution to your question is given by
$$
n = e^{W(c\log 2)}  = \frac{{c\log 2}}{{W(c\log 2)}}.
$$
For $c=1000$, this gives $n \approx 140.2217$.
The function $W$ is standard ([ProductLog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html) in Wolfram Mathematica).

EDIT: For large $c$, a rough but very simple approximation to the solution $n$ of $n^n = 2^c$ can be obtained as follows (cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/how-does-lamberts-w-behave-near/27372#27372), also for improvement of the approximation):
$$
n \approx (c\log 2)[\log (c\log 2)]^{1/\log (c\log 2) - 1} .
$$
For example, for $c=1000$ this gives $n \approx 141.2083$, not far from the exact value of about $140.2217$.

Comment: The wolframalpha link in the question actually has the $n = \exp(W(c\log 2))$ solution. :)

Comment: @leif: I noticed that after I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, take the $log_2$ of both sides gives you:

$$n log_2(n) = c$$

You can use Newton's method to solve this:

$$x_0 = c$$
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - (x_k log(x_k) - c log(2))/(1 + log(x_k))$$

where now "log" is the natural logarithm.

This gives the solution $n \sim x_4 = 140.221667$.

Starting with a better $x_0$, like $x_0=c / log(c)$ gives you even faster convergence.  With c=1000 or c=1000000, the value $x_3$ is correct with an error of $10^{-8}$.