# Approximating Lambert W for input below 0

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, approximation

As a small part of a much bigger project, I need to be able to approximate the numerical output of the Lambert W function.  I have found decent approximations (good up to at least 4 decimal places), for W for inputs on $[3,\infty)$ and $[0,3)$.  I thought this was going to be sufficient, but it turns out much of the input to the function will have to be below zero.  What is a good (and not too complicated) approximation of W for negative input?  Keep in mind I'm a programmer, not a mathematician.

Comment: Might as well link to the two questions about approximating the Lambert function at [$z=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26682) and at [$z=\infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27355)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're going for the principal branch, you'll want the expansion of the Lambert function $W(z)$ about the branch point $z=-e^{-1}$:

$$W(z)=-1+t-\frac{t^2}{3}+\frac{11}{72}t^3+\dots$$

where $t=\sqrt{2ez+2}$. If you require more terms, section 3 of [this paper](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/CorlessJeffreyKnuth.pdf) mentions the (complicated!) recurrence required to generate the coefficients of this series, as well as the adjustments you need to make if what you require is the "lower" branch $W_{-1}(z)$ (hint: you futz with the square root).

Alternatively, Winitzki gives in [his paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.90.6481) a convenient approximation for the principal branch for arguments near the branch point:

$$W(z)\approx\frac{ez}{1+\left((e-1)^{-1}-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2ez+2}}\right)^{-1}}$$

---

Here's a graphical side-by side comparison of three approximants over the interval $(-e^{-1},0)$. The plots are of functions of the form $f(z)-W(z)$, where $f(z)$ is one of the following: the first five terms of the branch point series, a $(3,2)$ Padé approximant constructed from the series,

$$W(z)\approx\frac{-1+\frac16 t+\frac{257}{720}t^2+\frac{13}{720}t^3}{1+\frac56 t+\frac{103}{720}t^2}, \qquad t=\sqrt{2ez+2}$$

and the Winitzki approximant:

[image: Lambert function approximants over (-1/e,0)]

Comment: Thanks!  Just so I understand the math, the first approximation you list here is taken from the series expansion of the function, correct?

Comment: Yes @Graham, it's the series about the branch point. Just generate as many terms of the series as needed, or construct a Padé approximant from it.