# $x^x = y$. Given $y$, find $x$.

Tags: exponentiation

Title is fairly self-explanatory. For example, for $y=27$, $x$ would be $3$. Specifically I was trying to find $x$ given $y = 10^{100}$, but I'd like to know how to solve it for any value of $y$.

Comment: $x=\exp W(\ln y)$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: In general, it requires a non-trivial function: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x

Comment: Re: your question of which areas of math this falls into, it falls into any of the categories of numerical methods, special functions and good old calculus.

Comment: @Timothy smith, it's seems to determine nature of x and y ? do you meant in integer ? or real numbers ?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/538495) answers a very similar question, and presents an algorithm to compute Lambert W.

Comment: This question asks ***how*** to solve this equation. The answers in the [cited original](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x) do not show how to get the formula given in the accepted answer, nor do they show how to compute Lambert W without a CAS to do so.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
x^x&=y\\ 
x\log x&=\log y\\ 
e^{\log x}\log x&=\log y\\ 
\log x&=W(\log y)\\
x&=e^{W(\log y)}\\
\end{align}$$
Where $W(x)$ is the ProductLog function, defined as the inverse of $[f(x)=xe^x]$

For your number:
$$\begin{align}
x^x&=10^{100}\\ 
x\log x&=\log 10^{100}\\ 
e^{\log x}\log x&=\log 10^{100}\\ 
\log x&=W(\log 10^{100})\\
x&=e^{W(100\log 10)}\\
x&\approx 56.9
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $x \ln x = \ln y$, so you can use binary search on $f(x) = x \ln x$ to get a pretty good estimate of the value. But you're not going to get a "closed form" formula for $x$ in this case.

It may be easier to use $\log_{10}$. For instance, in this case, you'd get
$$
x \log_{10}(x) = 100
$$
so $x$ is between $0$ and $100$. Trying $x = 10$ gives a too-small value (namely 10), so $x = 10^{1.5}$ might be better: you get $10^{1.5} \cdot 1.5 \approx 31.62 \cdot 1.5 \approx 45$. So the right $x$ is somewhere between 30 and 100.

Comment: Thanks, I'll research it. I edited the comment because I didn't see all the answers the first time.

Comment: I'm afraid this math is beyond me but it was nice to satisfy my curiosity. (I approximated x to four decimal places given y = 10^100.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :look  [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples). solutions represented as:

$$x=\frac{\ln(y)}{W(\ln y)}$$