# Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ at $0.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Taylor expansion for the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$$ at $a=0.$ I have looked up the Taylor expansion and concluded that it would be sufficient to show that
\begin{eqnarray} f^{(2k)}(0) & = & (-1)^{k}(2k)! \\ f^{(2k+1)}(0) & = & 0 \end{eqnarray}

The problem I am having is that the derivatives of $f$ are horrid - even proving them to be of a particular form seems hopeless. For example, I have tried without success to show that $$ f^{(2k)}(x) = \frac{(2k)!\left( (-1)^{k} + p(x) \right)}{(x^{2}+1)^{2k+1}} $$ where $p$ is a polynomial satisfying $p(0) = p^{\prime}(0) = 0$ and similar for $f^{(2k+1)}.$

I am sure that there is some trick I am missing. The book I am reading hasn't yet covered the binomial expansion for non-integer exponents and so it would seem circular to have to use the binomial expansion for $(1+x^{2})^{-1}.$

How do I derive the Taylor polynomial of order $2n$ at $0$ for $f$?

Comment: Trick: If you find any power series expansion of $f$, that **is** the Taylor expansion. So just find a power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ in the most convenient way.

Comment: If you want to compute this Taylor series directly (I.e. not by function composition) then the chain rule is your friend...

Comment: Also, note that $f(x)$ is an even function . What does that tell you about its odd derivatives?

Comment: That is a very useful observation, thank you: $f^{(2k+1)}(0) = 0$ because $f^{(2k)}$ is an even function for all $k.$

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier to use a geometric series to find the Taylor series. Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Now substitute $-x^2$ in for $x$ to find:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Note that the radius of convergence of the geometric series is 1. That is is works provided $|x|<1$. This also means that the new series is valid provided $|-x^2| < 1$, which means $|x|<1$. Hence it has the same radius of convergence.

Comment: Out of interest, does this generalise? Am I right in thinking that, if $p(x)$ is any polynomial, we could find the expansion of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+p(x)}$ as $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}p(x)^{k} $$ provided that $|p(x)|<1$?

Comment: Yes you can :) As long as the term on the inside is bounded by one, you may apply this.

Comment: Where $|p(x)| > 1$, you can divide out a factor of $p(x)$: $\frac{1}{1+p(x)} = \frac{1}{p(x)} \frac{1}{1+1/p(x)}$. Then do the same thing. The result is a series in negative powers of $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Direct Taylor expansion can be managed.
Let us rewrite the relation $y=\frac1{1+x^2}$ as
$$(1+x^2)y=1.$$
Then by successive derivations,
$$2xy+(1+x^2)y'=0,$$
$$2y+4xy'+(1+x^2)y''=0,$$
$$6y'+6xy''+(1+x^2)y'''=0,$$
$$12y''+8xy'''+(1+x^2)y''''=0,$$
$$20y'''+10xy''''+(1+x^2)y'''''=0,$$
$$30y''''+12xy'''''+(1+x^2)y''''''=0,$$
$$...$$
$$n(n-1)y^{(n-2)}+2nxy^{(n-1)}+(1+x^2)y^{(n)}=0.$$
(from a row to the next, the coefficient of the middle term increases by $2$, and the coefficient of the left term is the sum of the coefficients of the middle terms.)

When setting $x=0$, this reduces to
$$y=1,$$
$$y'=0,$$
$$2y+y''=0,$$
$$6y'+y'''=0,$$
$$12y''+y''''=0,$$
$$20y'''+y'''''=0,$$
$$30y''''+y''''''=0,$$
$$...$$
$$n(n-1)y^{(n-2)}+y^{(n)}=0.$$
Then by recurrence, $$y^{(2k)}=(-1)^k(2k)!y=(-1)^k(2k)!,\\y^{(2k+1)}=(-1)^k(2k+1)!y'=0.$$

Comment: You can generalize this method to any rational fraction $y=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$; you will observe that the derivatives follow a linear recurrence of order $\deg(Q)$ with coefficients equal to the coefficients of $Q$ multiplied by Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had started to spot a pattern like this as I was differentiating before I became disheartened and gave up so it is great to see that it can be done this way, and even better that it generalises to quotients of polynomials.

Comment: From previous attempts on similar problems, I noticed that it is beneficial to work around the derivation of quotients, or if not possible, prefer $\frac{x'}{y}-\frac{xy'}{y^2}$ over $\frac{x'y-xy'}{y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the technique! Very cool~

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $|t| < 1$ the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1+t}$ is
$$ \frac{1}{1+t} = 1 - t + t^2 - t^3 + t^4 + ... $$
Now insert $t = x^2$ to get
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + x^8 + ... $$
and you see there are no odd power terms in $x$.

Comment: Gosh, that almost seems too good to be true. Since we have now found the Taylor expansion by a method not involving differentiation, could we use this expansion to deduce that $f^{(2k)}(0) = (-1)^{k}(2k)!$ ? Is this ever used as a way of evaluating the $k^{\text{th}}$ derivative for tricky functions?

Comment: If a function has a power series representation at a specified point, it is unique. So yes, the conclusion is immediate.

Comment: @Shai Yes, in fact, this is a very common strategy for evaluating such derivatives when the series expansion is tractable through other means.

Answer (score 2):

Let us generalize the problem. We want expand $\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ about $a$ **providing** we know Taylor series of
$$
\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n\qquad;\qquad\text{for $|y|<1$}.\tag1
$$
Rewrite
\begin{align}
\frac1{1+x^2}&=\frac1{1+a-(a-x^2)}\\
&=\frac1{a+1}\left[\frac1{1-\left(\dfrac{a-x^2}{a+1}\right)}\right].\tag2
\end{align}
Setting $y=\dfrac{a-x^2}{a+1}$ and using $(1)$, then $(2)$ becomes
$$
\color{blue}{\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{a+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a-x^2}{a+1}\right)^n}\qquad;\qquad\text{for $\color{red}{\left|\dfrac{a-x^2}{a+1}\right|<1}$}.\tag3
$$
The last step is setting $a=0$.

Comment: Wow! This is very nice answer! I think the best so far. +1 for the generalisation!

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+(-1)^nx^n+o(x^n),$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots+(-1)^nx^{2n}+o(x^{2n}).$$