# Lambert- W -Function calculation?

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I have  an equation of the form:

$$  n \log n = x $$

Upon searching I came across the term  "Lambert- W -Function" but couldn't find a proper method for evaluation, and neither any computer code for it's evaluation.

Any ideas as to how I can evaluate?

Comment: Do you mean an evaluation of the function for a certain argument? Sorry, just trying to make sure I understand your question.

Comment: Well,this is more of a programming question,but was just wondering if it could be solved manually. For given value of x,can we find n?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html give several series expansions. See the equations (11), (13) and (14).

Comment: wikipedia has a derivate containing code ("wikicode"? "Rosettastone"?). I found it easy to find a recursive programming-example, translatable into Pari/GP

Comment: $n\ln(n)=x\implies \exp(n\ln(n))=\exp(x)\implies n^n=\exp(x)\implies n=\frac{x}{W(x)}$, using Example 2 of the wiki article on $W$.

Answer (score 8):

Let us consider the function $$f(x)=x \log(x)-a$$ Effcetively, the solution of $f(x)=0$ is given by $$x=\frac{a}{W(a)}$$ and, if I properly understood, you look for a computation method for getting $W(a)$.

From definition $W(a)$ is defined such that $a=W(a)e^{W(a)}$ so Newton method seems to be (and is) very good.

I strongly suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. In the paragraph entitled "Numerical evaluation", they give Newton and Halley formulae (the latest one has been massively used by Corless et al. to compute $W(a)$.

In the same Wikipedia page, you will find very nice and efficient approximations of $W(a)$ for small and large values. These estimates will allow you to start really close to the solution.

If I may underline one thing which is really nice : all derivatives od $W(a)$ express as functions of $a$ and $W(a)$ itself and this is extremely convenient.

You could be interested by
 http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/toms443/toms443.html
where the source code is available.

Answer (score 4):

Although an old post, I'm surprised nobody mentioned this:

$$n\log n=(e^{\log n})\log n=x$$

Now it should be obvious on how to proceed.

$$W(x)=\log n$$

$$e^{W(x)}=n$$

And because $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$, $e^W(x)=\frac{x}{W(x)}$ so,

$$\frac{x}{W(x)}=n$$

Answer (score 4):

Although this has already been answered, I think a step by step explanation is more informative than a general one.

The following is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
n \ln (n) =x \quad & \Rightarrow \quad \ln n^n=x \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad n^n=e^x \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad n=e^{x/n} \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad n \times \frac{x}{n}=\frac{x}{n}e^{x/n} \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad x=\frac{x}{n}e^{x/n} \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad W(x)=W \left(\frac{x}{n}e^{x/n} \right) \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad W(x)=\frac{x}{n} \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad \boxed{n=\frac{x}{W(x)}} \\
& \Rightarrow \quad n=\frac{x}{x/e^{W(x)}}  \quad \text{(since 
 $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$)}\\
& \Rightarrow \quad \boxed{n=e^{W(x)}} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: How do we replace $\log(x)$ with $\ln(x)$?

Comment: @Mathrix Often \log is used as \ln. Sometimes (mostly on calculators) it stands for \log_10.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Matlab or want to look at a robust (but simple) implementation of the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ($W_0$ branch only) using Halley's method, [see my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/464668/80812).

As an alternative to @ClaudeLeibovici's more general answer, an equation specifically of the form $n \text{ln}(n) = x$ might best be solved and analyzed using the simpler [Wright $\omega$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Omega_function):

$$n = \frac{x}{\omega(-ln(1/x))}$$

Matlab has [`wrightOmega`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/wrightomega.html) and Maple has [`Wrightomega`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx) to evaluate this function symbolically. See Corless and Jeffrey, 2002, [The Wright omega Function](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/wrightomega.pdf) (PDF) for further details. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be support for this function [in SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2851) or SymPy.

The Wright $\omega$ function can also be evaluated numerically. See Lawrence, et al., 2012, [Algorithm 917: Complex Double-Precision Evaluation of the Wright ω Function](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2168779). I've implemented this algorithm in Matlab – you can [find it on GitHub here](https://github.com/horchler/wrightOmegaq). Evaluating this numerically is 3+ orders of magnitude faster than evaluating it symbolically. If your $x$ parameter is constrained in particular ways (e.g., real-valued), you may be able to simplify your algorithm – see the Lawrence, et al. paper and the comments in my `wrightOmega` code.