# Solving $p^x = x^q$

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

What is the best approach for solving the equations of the form

> $p^x = x^q$ ; where $p$ and $q$ are some constants.

Basically, I wanted to solve $2^x = x^2$ to analyze algorithms with respective growth functions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Except that in this case, the two $y$'s in your equation are different, but given, constants instead of an unknown.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I meant you, not the answer. Also in the case the OP asks you have to use $\lg$ not $\ln$.

Comment: why not the $\ln$ ?

Comment: it is the logarithmus naturalis as you know

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271139/how-to-solve-x2-ex/1271147) is a very similar question on MSE, for $p=2$ and $q=e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot :) That is helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all solutions of $a^b = b^a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871169/find-all-solutions-of-ab-ba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such equations can be solved using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), defined to be an inverse function of $f(x)=xe^x$. Because $f$ is not injective, the Lambert W function is in fact a multifunction. It can be evaluated numerically, however there is a closed form for some values of $x$.

Now let us solve your equation:
$$p^x=x^q \\ p^xx^{-q}=1$$

using the properties of $e$ and natural logarithms
$$e^{x\ln p}x^{-q}=1 \\ e^{-\frac{x\ln p}{q}}x=1$$

Now we multiply by $-\frac{\ln p}{q}$ in order to use the definition of $W(x)$:
$$-\frac{x\ln p}{q}\cdot e^{-\frac{x\ln p}{q}} =-\frac{\ln p}{q} \\ -\frac{x\ln p}{q}=W\left(-\frac{\ln p}{q} \right)$$

Finally, after some transformations we see that
$$\boxed{x=-\dfrac{q\, W\left( -\frac{\ln p}{q}\right)}{\ln p}}$$
And that's the closest you can get to a closed form.

Comment: (+1) it is worth being careful with this, however: it looks like the argument to $W$, $\frac{- \ln p}{q}$, is negative. That means $W$ is multivalued, so there are two solutions! And if $\frac{- \ln p}{q} < \frac{-1}{e}$, then there are no solutions.