# How to manually calculate/approximate a specific value of the Lambert W function

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I have read a few other posts with similar question but all of them are for a positive value of x, and/or require you to use a computer to compute the result.

I was wondering if it is possible to manually calculate/approximate the Lambert W function for an x which has two real solutions thus meaning $-1/e < x < 0$.

A simpler way to formulate my question would be to ask, how to manually calculate the numerical values of:

$W_0 (x)$ and $W_-1 (x)$ where $-1/e < x < 0 $

(I would prefer not to use newton's method)

Comment: You could be interested by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420119/lambert-function-approximation-w-0-branch/2614315#2614315 which I forgot (age problems !!)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465183) gives an iterative method for computing Lambert W. It gives either branch for negative arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just a partial answer.*

Since I faced this specific problem a few years ago for $W_0(x)$, what I found as "best"  are  Padé approximants.

The simplest ones are

For  $\color{red}{-\frac 1e \leq x \leq -\frac 1{2e}}$
$$W_0(x) \approx \frac{-1+\frac{14\sqrt{2}}{45}  \sqrt{e x+1}+\frac{301}{540} (e x+1)}{1+\frac{31\sqrt{2}}{45}  \sqrt{e x+1}+\frac{83}{540}
   (e x+1)}\tag 1$$ 
For  $\color{red}{-\frac 1{2e} \leq x \leq 0}$

$$W_0(x) \approx \frac{x+\frac{4 }{3}x^2}{1+\frac{7 }{3}x+\frac{5 }{6}x^2}\tag 2$$

For sure, for more accuracy, I built similar expressions with more terms.

**Edit**

For the other branch, you can use

$$W_{-1}(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(-2+L_2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\frac{L_2(-12+36L_2-22L_2^2+3L_2^3)}{12L_1^4}+\frac{L_2(60-300L_2+350L_2^2-125 L_2^3+12 L_2^4)}{60L_1^5}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(-x)$ and $L_2=\log(-L1)$

**Update**

Calling $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ the expressions given in $(1)$ and $(2)$, let us consider the error function
$$\Phi(a)=\int_{-\frac 1 e}^a \left(W(x)-f(x)\right)^2+\int^0_a \left(W(x)-g(x)\right)^2$$ and get the following values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & 10 ^{10} \,\Phi(a) \\
 -0.350 & 472433 \\
 -0.325 & 72500 \\
 -0.300 & 13455 \\
 -0.275 & 2646 \\
 -0.250 & 523 \\
 -0.225 & 109 \\
\color{red}{ -0.200} &\color{red}{ 44} \\
 -0.175 & 57 \\
 -0.150 & 100 \\
 -0.125 & 168 \\
 -0.100 & 269 \\
 -0.075 & 411 \\
 -0.050 & 605 \\
 -0.025 & 863 \\
  0.000 & 1197
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: are their approximations of the W-1 branch?
In "cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf" at equation (4.20) there is an equation that would allow the computation of the result (if I understood properly), but I don't know how I could apply it without the help of a computer.

Comment: @AlexHal. See my edit.