# How can I calculate $W(-x)$ using $W(x)$?

Tags: lambert-w

The question is with regards to [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

Given $W(x)$, I need to calculate $W(-x)$.

Is there any way to do that?

I've searched through [the function identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities), but couldn't find anything useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some context on the question? Where does it come from, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @GEdgar I think you mean: if $a = W(x)$ and $b=W(-x)$, can we write $a$ in terms of $b$? This is equivalent to: if $ae^a =x$ and $be^b=-x$, can we write $a$ in terms of $b$?

Comment: @JensRenders  You are right.  Then this amounts to: solve $ae^a = -be^b$ for $b$.

Comment: @GEdgar Ineed, but without evaluating Lambert $W$ in $-ae^a$ explicitly, because $-ae^a$ is just $-x$.

Comment: Do you want the real-valued W function?  In order for both $x$ and $-x$ to belong to the domain, you need $-1/e < x < 1/e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just the start of what I am working on (hoping to get something better later).*

Since we are restricted to the range $-\frac 1 e \leq x\leq \frac 1 e$, we could consider, around $x=0$ the expansion
$$W(-x)\, W(x)=-x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \,x^{2n}$$ where the $a_n$'s are the sequence
$$\left\{1,2,\frac{22}{3},\frac{168}{5},\frac{18142}{105},\frac{2702944}{2835},\frac{
   286762684}{51975},\frac{66973259776}{2027025},\frac{9972382736698}{49116375},\cdots\right\}$$ which is not recognized by $OEIS$ which lead to quite good results except very close to $x=\frac 1 e$.

Similarly, we could write
$$W(-x)+ W(x)=-2x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \,x^{2n}$$ where the $b_n$'s are the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{8}{3},\frac{54}{5},\frac{16384}{315},\frac{156250}{567},\frac{298598
   4}{1925},\frac{7909306972}{868725},\frac{35184372088832}{638512875},\frac{508373
   1656658}{14889875},\cdots\right\}$$

If required, these series expansions could be made much more compact transforming them is Padé approximants.

Similarly, we could write
$$\frac{W(-x)\, W(x)}{W(-x)+W(x)}=\frac 12-\frac {x^2}3\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \,x^{2n}$$ where the $c_n$'s are the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{38}{15},\frac{634}{63},\frac{75568}{1575},\frac{39393118}{155925},
   \frac{301414530016}{212837625},\frac{1763848931644}{212837625},\frac{2716085710533
   376}{54273594375},\cdots\right\}$$

**Edit**

We could do better using  [Winitzki's approximation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=10F960827998DC1CD118274268F431BF?doi=10.1.1.90.6481&)
$$W(x)\sim\frac{e x}{1+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 e x+2}}}}\qquad \text{where}\qquad a=\frac{1}{e-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ which is very good for the range of interest. So,
$$\color{blue}{W(-x)=-W(x)\,\,\frac{1+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 e x+2}}}}{1+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-2 e   x}}}}}$$ Since this is an approximation, we can use $a=-\frac 18$ and even retain
$$W(-x)=-W(x)\frac{\left(4 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1-e x}\right) \left(7 \sqrt{1+e x}+4
   \sqrt{2}\right)}{\left(4 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1+e   x}\right)\left(7 \sqrt{1-e x}+4 \sqrt{2}\right) }$$

A few values for comparison
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
   x   & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 -0.35 & +0.261884 & +0.267777 \\
 -0.30 & +0.231621 & +0.236755 \\
 -0.25 & +0.199919 & +0.203888 \\
 -0.20 & +0.166157 & +0.168916 \\
 -0.15 & +0.129852 & +0.131515 \\
 -0.10 & +0.090490 & +0.091277 \\
 -0.05 & +0.047464 & +0.047672 \\
 +0.00 & +0.000000 & +0.000000 \\
 +0.05 & -0.052937 & -0.052706 \\
 +0.10 & -0.112804 & -0.111833 \\
 +0.15 & -0.181790 & -0.179491 \\
 +0.20 & -0.263475 & -0.259171 \\
 +0.25 & -0.364499 & -0.357403 \\
 +0.30 & -0.500250 & -0.489402 \\
 +0.35 & -0.732766 & -0.716639
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Speaking about Padé approximants, we could also write (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/approximation-for-lambert-w-function-near-zero/26690#26690rep=rep1&type=pdf))
$$W(x) \sim \log(1+x)\,P_{n,n}(x)$$ and then write
$$W(-x)\sim W(x)\,\, \frac{\log(1-x) } {\log(1+x) }\,\, \frac{P_{n,n}(-x) } {P_{n,n}(x) }$$
Since the linked page gives the coefficients for $n=2$, I give you the next
$$P_{3,3}(x)=\frac{1+\frac{26213 }{5194}x+\frac{82391 }{10388}x^2+\frac{85291
  }{22260}x^3 } {1+\frac{14405 }{2597}x+\frac{76259 }{7791}x^2+\frac{564353
   }{103880}x^3 }$$

In the linked answer, the answerer wrote that *"probably one might do better with a minimax rational approximation"*. This is what I did for $-\frac 1e \leq x \leq \frac 1e$ writing
$$W(x)\sim Q_{3,3}(x)= x\,\frac{a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2}{b_0+b_1 x+b_2x^2+b_3 x^3}$$ the optimum parameters being
$$a_0=1+\frac{13489}{3916800 e^6}+\frac{13489}{326400 e^4}-\frac{121401}{343400 e^2}$$ $$ a_1=\frac{228}{85}-\frac{13489}{326400 e^4}-\frac{94423}{343400 e^2}\qquad a_2=\frac{451}{340}+\frac{13489}{137360 e^2}$$
$$b_0=1+\frac{13489}{326400 e^4}-\frac{121401}{343400 e^2}$$
$$b_1=\frac{313}{85}-\frac{26978}{42925 e^2}\qquad b_2=\frac{1193}{340}\qquad b_3=\frac{133}{204}$$

So, the proposed approximation is
$$W(-x) \sim W(x)\,\, \frac{Q_{3,3}(-x) } {Q_{3,3}(x) }$$

A new table for comparison with the previous one
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.35 & +0.274095 & +0.267777 \\
 -0.30 & +0.236981 & +0.236755 \\
 -0.25 & +0.203889 & +0.203888 \\
 -0.20 & +0.168917 & +0.168916 \\
 -0.15 & +0.131517 & +0.131515 \\
 -0.10 & +0.091277 & +0.091277 \\
 -0.05 & +0.047672 & +0.047672 \\
 +0.00 & +0.000000 & +0.000000 \\
 +0.05 & -0.052706 & -0.052706 \\
 +0.10 & -0.111832 & -0.111833 \\
 +0.15 & -0.179489 & -0.179491 \\
 +0.20 & -0.259170 & -0.259171 \\
 +0.25 & -0.357401 & -0.357403 \\
 +0.30 & -0.488936 & -0.489402 \\
 +0.35 & -0.700120 & -0.716639
\end{array}
\right)$$
which seems to be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $ae^a=-be^b$ for $b$.
I found nothing explicit, but the Taylor series near $a=0$ is
$$
b=-a-2\,{a}^{2}-4\,{a}^{3}-{\frac{28}{3}}{a}^{4}-24\,{a}^{5}-{\frac{
328}{5}}{a}^{6}-{\frac{8416}{45}}{a}^{7}-{\frac{173216}{315}}{a}^{8}-{
\frac{104288}{63}}{a}^{9}-{\frac{2878496}{567}}{a}^{10}+O \left( {a}^{11
} \right) 
$$

Looking in the [Online Enyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A007889), I conjecture that this is
$$
b = -\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{S_{j-1} 2^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}\;a^j
$$
where $(S_j)_{j\ge 0}$ is the sequence [A007889](http://oeis.org/A007889).  But it turns out that is not surprising.  One of the formulas for the exponential generating function of A007889 involves the Lambert W function.