# Better approximation for Lambert W Function near zero

Tags: polynomials, approximation, lambert-w

I've looking for a polynomial approximation for [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) around zero.

I am aiming at the range of $0\leq x\leq e$, and if possible then even $-e\leq x\leq e$.

The [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) (when limited to a finite number of iterations of course), yields a polynomial approximation for the range of $-1/e\leq x\leq1/e$.

I've found the following polynomial approximation for the range of $0\leq x\leq e$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26690/402209):

$$W_0(z)\approx\ln(1+z)\frac{1+\frac{123}{40}z+\frac{21}{10}z^2}{1+\frac{143}{40}z+\frac{713}{240}z^2}$$

I've tested it to my satisfaction, but I would like ask a few questions here:

1. Can it be easily extended to the range of $-e\leq x\leq e$?
2. The author of that answers explains something about *Padé approximant*, and says that one might do a better approximation (which he/she did not bother to find due to the question in context). Would anyone be able to shed light on how to compute a better polynomial approximation?
3. Is there perhaps a different approach to my goal, unrelated of the answer above?

Thank you!

Comment: These are not polynomial approximations.  They are rational approximations to $W(x)/\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimax rational approximation of $W(x)/\ln(1+x)$ on $[0,e]$ with numerator and denominator of degree $2$ is, according to Maple,
$$ \frac{0.0396202320 + 0.1961951280 x + 0.1702729841 x^2}{0.0396188863 + 0.2161222712 x + 0.2405866129 x^2}$$
which has maximum absolute error approximately $0.00003396612388$ on that interval.

You're not going to be able to get an approximation on $[-e, e]$ because $W(x)$ has a branch point at $-1/e$ and all its branches are complex for $x < -1/e$.  You could look for approximations on $[-1/e, e]$.   Thus the 
minimax rational approximation of $W(x)/\ln(1+x)$ on $[-1/e, e]$ with numerator and denominator of degree $2$ is

$$\frac{0.0663274708 + 0.2304903265 x + 0.1716240158 x^2}{0.0663270883 + 0.2636065188 x + 0.2426002763 x^2} $$
with maximum absolute error approximately $0.00004705730323$ on that interval.

You can get better accuracy with higher-degree approximations.

Comment: Thank you! Your last (second) approximation is for $x\in[-1/e,e]$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Awesome (and very useful) answer, thank you very much!!!

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing: since I am already handling the range $[-1/e,1/e]$ accurately, I technically need to handle only the range $[1/e,e]$. Will Maple generate a more accurate 2nd-degree approximation if I narrow the input range in your first example?

Comment: Yes, on a smaller interval you should get a better approximation.  In this case, for degrees $2$ and $2$ Maple is telling me "error curve fails to oscillate sufficiently; try different degrees".  With numerator of degree $1$ and denominator $3$, it gives me
$${\frac { 0.276972170484786+ 0.332660424982433\,x}{ 0.277527230334148
+ 0.466289676939177\,x+ 0.00150785702317642\,{x}^{2}-
 0.000244712398927012\,{x}^{3}}}
$$
with maximum error $6.281026638 \times 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually downloaded Maple already, but needed to learn how to use it. +10 (if I could).